# Open a workbook without the Auto_Openening

Tags: java, excel, vb6, jacob, vba

> How i can open a workbook without the Auto_Open running using Jacob ??

Comment: If `Auto_Open` does not provide the specification of use, describe that exact specification.  Otherwise this seems an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) (or a close variant).

Comment: I would like to call a Subroutine from VB Macro without running this macro or it contains a workbook_Open which triggers automatically when i do: ` Dispatch workBook = workbooks.call(excel, "Open",file.getAbsolutePath()).toDispatch() `  using Jacob

Comment: finaly, I resolve my problem by this instruction: `excel.setProperty("EnableEvents", new Variant(false));`

Comment: you're welcom @khalidlblid :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
excel.setProperty("EnableEvents", new Variant(false));
```